# Установка картинки png на элемент

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно установить картинку в формате png на кнопку, как это можно сделать? Я имею ввиду, что мне нужно заменить стандартную текстуру кнопки картинкой. Сама картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
button {
  background: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/KAzh4.png) center;
}

.large {
  height: 1080px;
  width: 1080px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 128px;
}
```

```html
<button>Кнопка</button>
<br>
<button class=large>Кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Про свойство `background` не слышали?

```css
a {
color:#fff;
font-family:sans-serif;
display:inline-block;
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAzh4.png);
background-position:center;
background-size:100%;
padding:40px;
}
```

```html
<a>Скачать</a>
```